# Trying to set form input value using js-cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a landing page that sets a cookie on your machine when you arrive:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cookies.set('Web_Lead_Specific_Source__c', 'PPC', { expires: 365 });
</script>
```

On a separate page I have a form with a hidden field:

```
<input name="Web_Lead_Specific_Source__c" value="">
```

I'm trying to load the value with "PPC" if the user has visited the landing page. The following code is not working:

```
Cookies.get('Web_Lead_Specific_Source__c');  => 'PPC'
```

I'm sure I'm missing something.

Comment: can you be more specific on "the following code is not working" Are you getting an error?

Comment: Try to use jquery cookie is more simple : [jquery-cookie](http://www.sitepoint.com/eat-those-cookies-with-jquery/)

Comment: No I'm not getting an error. The desired value "PPC" is not populating in the input field. I'm attempting to get this working using https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie. I'm trying to follow the simple steps laid out on the git hub page, but can't get it to work. The cookie is being created fine, I just can't get it to populate in the input field. Thanks for the help on this!

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, js-cookie is the same as jquery-cookie, why do you think the jquery-cookie API is better if js-cookie API is clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **get**ting the cookie is not enough, you need to set into the input field:

```
var leadType = Cookies.get('Web_Lead_Specific_Source__c');
var target = document.getElementsByName('Web_Lead_Specific_Source__c')[ 0 ];
target.value = leadType;
```

js-cookie is responsible only to set and get the value from the **browser cookies**, it doesn't have any knowledge of the **elements in the page**, that's something different.

Here is a working example with proper object oriented naming to prevent confusion: http://jsfiddle.net/f1fkydwh/

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. This is working for me only if the input field is displayed. In my case the input field is hidden so it's not working for me. I notice that even when the input field is displayed and all is working correctly if I inspect the input element the "value=" property is still blank. See your jsfiddle example. I need for the input "value=" property to populate with the cookie data. Follow me? Thanks again for everyone's input on this!

Comment: Can you explain your use case please?

Comment: Sure, I have landing page that installs a cookie with the content of "PPC" on your computer whenever you visit the page. On a separate website I have a contact form with a hidden input field. I want to be able to fill in the "value=" of that hidden field with the "PPC" content of the cookie. I tested the input field without it being hidden and it works visually by populating the actual field, but it doesn't actually populate the "value=" in the source code when you look at the html. I need the value to be able populate in the source code so that when the form is submitted it'll read "PPC".

Comment: I understand, then instead of `target.value`, try using `target.setAttribute( "value", leadType )` instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/element/setAttribute

Comment: This worked perfectly:

`var leadType = Cookies.get('Web_Lead_Specific_Source__c');
var target = document.getElementsByName('Web_Lead_Specific_Source__c')[ 0 ];
target.setAttribute( "value", leadType )`
Thanks for helping me with this!